# Shortcut not working in Ubuntu 17.04 gnome

Tags: shortcut-keys, 17.04

I am trying to increase the volume by this command: `pactl set-sink-volume @DEFAULT_SINK@ 150%`
This command works if I write it in terminal but doesn't work if I create a keyboard shortcut of this command. I have several other shortcuts working properly. I have also tried various keys for this command but none of them works. Do anybody have any idea why is it happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a bash script with this command, save it in any place (I suggest /opt). See:

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/bin/pactl set-sink-volume @DEFAULT_SINK@ 150%
```

So you can attach it to a shortcut as you already did:

[image]

Comment: It worked! But what was the reason behind it?

Comment: It's because not always shortcuts don't read PATH variable as terminal session does.